# How to disable Warnings of Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

I have this error:

> error C4996: 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

and similar errors pop up when I use other old C functions.
My question is: Is there a way that these errors show up like Warnings, without actually preventing the code from compiling ?

Comment: Did you [search](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS&emptyWatermark=true&searchButtonTooltip=Search%20MSDN&ac=4)?

Comment: I have been searching since yesterday, but apparently I was using wrong keywords.
Checking your link now, thanks in advance :)

Comment: How to disable POSIX-related deprecation warnings by defining _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must define `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` in the preprocessor settings of your project, or `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` at the beginning of your file where you use `fopen()`. Or just use `fopen_s()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can simply right click on "YourFile.cpp" file and choose "**Properties**"; Click on "**Configuration Properties**" and in the front part choose "**No**" for "**SDL checks**". It will consider these errors as warnings in the next compilation.

However you can prevent this property while creating a new project by **unticking** the "**Security Development Lifecycle (SDL) checks**" option.

The same for VS2013!